# Can you explain how these precision, recall and purity are calculated in this context?

Tags: data-mining

I am studying to get my first job as data scientist and I stumbled upon this. I have been banging my head on the wall for hrs to understand this concept. But couldn't get concrete answer. Just 1 example will be enough.

https://slideplayer.com/slide/14318989/
It is page number  34 of the given slide.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The definitions are given on slide 33. For example, for recall of each cluster you need to find

> n<sub>ik<sub>i</sub></sub>

which you can infer from the definition above:

> Assign to cluster *i* the class *k<sub>i</sub>* such that *k<sub>i</sub>*  = argmax<sub>j</sub>n<sub>ij</sub>

which simply says for each cluster, the index of the highest *n* is defined as *k<sub>i</sub>*. For the case of cluster 1 on the left, it is cluster 3, so the index is 3. which gives:

> n<sub>ik<sub>i</sub></sub> = n<sub>13</sub> = 85

and the denominator is

> c<sub>k<sub>i</sub></sub> = c<sub>3</sub> = 100

So you get the recall for cluster 1 on the left as 85/100.